# Convert image color space from RGB to opponent color

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I have found definition of opponent color space which is given by [formulas](http://refbase.cvc.uab.es/files/AVL2011b.pdf):

```
O1 = 1/sqrt(2) * (R - G)
O2 = 1/sqrt(6) * (R + G - 2B)
O3 = 1/sqrt(3) * (R + G + B)
```

In these formulas the R,G,B symbols are values of channels of original image in the RGB space.

The original image represented in the RGB color space is typical `uint8` image and the values are from [0, 255] range. Calculations are done by casting the image into `float`.

How the resulting image, especially O1 and O2 channels, could be scaled to have the same range [0, 255] and could be represented by `uint8` type?

And after scaling, is it possible to return from opponent color space into RGB space with image representing by `uint8` type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, let's look at O1... the maximum possible value of (R-G) is 255 if R=255 and G=0. The minimum possible value of (R-G) is -255 if R=0 and G=255.

So

```
-255/root2 <= O1 <= 255/root2
```

If we want that on the range 0 to 255, we'll need to add 255/root2 which will make it greater than or equal to zero and less than 510/root2, so we'll need to multiply by 255*root2/510.

Now O2... the maximum possible value of (R+G-2B) is 510, and the minimum is -510. So

```
-510/root6 <= O2 <= 510/root6
```

So, add 510/root6 and it'll be between 0 and 1020/root6, so we'll need to multiply by 255*root6/1020.

You can do O3 :-)